# Create a picker view to use on multiple ViewControllers

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uipickerview

My app has multiple screens all of which are different and not related however i must have a burger button which opens the same drop down menu on each screen.

Is it possible in iOS to create the menu once as a view and reuse it on each screen or do I have to create it on each ViewController and implement it.

Any explanation as to how to achieve this would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing would be to implement a custom view or custom control which you reuse in every Controller you want. The good thing is with the new storyboard and a xib file you can even see it in realtime in the storyboard (#ibdesignable).

Check out this: [Creating a Custom View That Renders in Interface Builder (Apple Documentation)](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwivydPEh7fLAhWq8nIKHQOYBN8QFggfMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Flibrary%2Fios%2Frecipes%2Fxcode_help-IB_objects_media%2FChapters%2FCreatingaLiveViewofaCustomObject.html&usg=AFQjCNFR_bC1ezT5Z3HdYImaAyUKH6Tuhg&sig2=WpST3BueYoO077aN7XQo-A)

Or a great tutorial: [Custom UI components](http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-custom-ui-components-live-rendering-xcode/)

Comment: both of them look awesome thanks. i think the first one from the apple documents will do the trick.